# Where (else) can be 301 redirect?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've run into an issue with 301 redirects recently. I was doing some of those for general on-site SEO and then I've noticed that someone working before me already did some 301s that were entirely in conflict with what I've planned.

Solution is simple - pick a different url, delete the unwanted 301 and make two 301s of your own to redirect both from the previous (unwanted) url and the current url to the new url, right? Here's the thing - I can't find where is the 301 the previous guy did.

It's apache and wordpress. I've checked vhosts, .htaccess (sometimes there can be more than one .htaccess file, I've checked for that too). There's also 301s from php via header redirect but I've checked all the obvious places for and the project is huge.

The question is - are there any other places the 301 can be? Any other ways I don't know of to do 301? Both in my setting (apache + wordpress) and in general?

Comment: Could be done via some plugin

Comment: You can turn on [Rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), that should show if it comes from .conf or .htaccess rewrite rules